# Capture.captureAudio() within a modal dialog on Android 8+ does not return until dispose of dialog

Tags: codenameone

I instantiate a modal dialog and have a button that executes Capture.captureAudio()
*On Android 8+ running on Samsung TAB S5e and Galaxy Tab A8 devices,*
Tapping the button opens the recording dialog as expected, however when tap "Save" we don't get the String that Capture.captureAudio() returns until I dispose the current dialog.
Then the Capture.captureAudio() results are returned to me.

Works correctly on IOS and PC.

My Dialog is executed on the EDT, the Capture.captureAudio() is executed from a lambda expression and on a separate EDT

Thoughts?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try showing the Dialog as modless using the `showModless()` method. Alternatively try using an `InteractionDialog` as discussed [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/picking-dialog-type.html).

We generally recommend avoiding `Dialog` for any complex UI especially one that might use the `invokeAndBlock` semantics. Nesting those can lead to unexpected side effects as you can see in this case. This only happens on iOS since the iOS implementation uses `invokeAndBlock()` internally